# Custom configuration for flutter format

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to add custom configurations to `flutter format` command? Say for instance, want to increase the number of characters in a line. I am looking for writing them in a separate configuration file (may be YAML) and while running `flutter format`, it should format based on those rules.

[Flutter Docs](https://flutter.io/formatting/) does not have anything mentioned.

Comment: what about this [formatter] (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_style)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are using IntelliJ IDEA
go to:

> Settings ->Editor ->code Style -> Dart

```
Say for instance, want to increase the number of characters in a line
```

change the  ***Right margin*** in ***Wrapping and braces*** 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

TL,DR

```
flutter format  lib/* -l 120
```

`flutter format` using `dartfmt` to do the job ([see here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/format.dart)), The rest args will be appended to `dartfmt`, so we can use `dartfmt` options.

`dartfmt --help` to get more options.

Also, see [dartfmt doc](https://dart.dev/tools/dartfmt)